# Retrieve the path of an ImageIcon

Tags: java, path

Is it possible to get the location of the file that an ImageIcon was created from?

Internally ImageIcon has a  transient private URL of its location, which when debugging will show its path, but I can't figure out how to access it. Any suggestions?

Here's what I mean,

```
public String getPath(ImageIcon icon){
    return ????;
}
```

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"*  You'll generally get better answers if you describe the goal you are trying to achieve, rather than the strategy you intend to use to achieve that goal.  What is the goal?

Comment: @Andrew Get a string representing the path of the underlying image from my image icon.

Comment: Suggestion: show how you create the ImageIcon, provide some context.  I'm *assuming* you mean in a JPanel but that's an *assumption* because you haven't provided enough detail.

Comment: @Charles *"..show how you create the ImageIcon, provide some context."* +1  Without understanding more, it is not easy to provide the best advice on this matter.

Comment: @Andrew I fail to see what else I could give you that would help anymore. I have an ImageIcon, I want to know if I can get it's path from it. Where is the confusion?

Comment: The confusion is why you'd want to do such a silly thing.  You create it didn't you?  If you did, the path is the same as whatever path you created it with.  So far you are not getting my points, and not answering my questions, so I am beginning to wonder if I can be of any help to you.  One last try.  How are you creating the `ImageIcon`?

Comment: @Andrew Where did I say I created it? I don't know, that is the point, it is provided through a remoted object and it can be created in any one of a hundred ways. This information has no bearing on the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection to access the private field, but if the `ImageIcon` wasn't created with a `URL` the field will be `null`. If you are creating the `ImageIcon`s yourself you could keep track of the `URL`s in a map.

```
ImageIcon icon = ...
Class<? extends ImageIcon> clazz = icon.getClass();
Field urlField = clazz.getDeclaredField("location");
urlField.setAccessible(true);

URL location = (URL) urlField.get(icon);
```

It is also worth considering that the field name may change in future versions, which may produce exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `getDescription()`?

I only say so because in the documentation for [`public ImageIcon(String filename)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29%29) it lists [`getDescription()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getDescription%28%29) under "See Also".

*Note: see Jeffrey's comment.*

Comment: +1, this will work if he doesn't provide a description separately in the constructor or set it with `setDescription(String)`.

Comment: @Jeffrey So what you guys are saying is that in the general case, there is no **guaranteed** way to get an ImageIcons original filepath except through reflection?

Comment: @Andrew Yup. Keeping track of it yourself is the only guaranteed way.